# VSCode throwing error when trying to launch Jupyter python interactive

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

1. Anaconda was previously installed
2. VS Code was installed
3. Python core was installed
4. Anaconda was removed
5. Everything re-installed

When I execute a python script from vscode using shift+F5 it throws this error. Cannot figure out how to solve as the error message says path not found, but those paths all exist. Any help is appreciated.

```
StdErr from ShellExec, The system cannot find the path specified for c:/Programming/python_application/env/Scripts/activate.bat && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py
```

Comment: Uninstall everything, remove all installation folders, then reinstall again.

Comment: @Hodja -Please enter 'python' in the cmd window to check whether Python is available. In addition, please reinstall the Python extension in VSCode and use the newly created project and [Python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).